# Подснежник в PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Как вывести данные с таблице в бд phpmyadmin ?

```
<?php
    /*$bd_name = 'prokofeva_sam';*/
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prokofeva_sam');
    /*mysql_select_db($bd_name, $link);*/

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo 'Ошибка в подклюении к базе данных('. mysqli_connect_errno().'): '. mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
        }
    else 
        {
            echo 'База данных подключена';
        }
?>

  <html>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Catalog</title>

  <body>
    <p>
      <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `catalogs`", $link);
                while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    echo "<p>".$result['name']."</p>";
                }
            ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из-за этой ошибки, не могу продолжить обучение

Comment: Вы подключайтесь к БД с помощью mysqli, а запрос к ней делаете через mysql функцию, будьте внимательнее.

Answer (score 0):

Значит так идем на официальный сайт php лезем в [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) и смотрим 
mysqli_query($link, query); первый аргумент подключение второй запрос ка базе а не наоборот. Насчет второй ошибки я порекомендовал бы использовать 1 функцию вместо while и mysqli_fetch_array() - это mysqli_fetch_assoc() и mysqli_fetch_all()